# Iterate 2 lists of same length; create a list of n consecutive numbers without using generators

Tags: python, list

I have seen questions asking about creating a list of N numbers in python. Say an input N = 6 should create [0,1,2,3,4,5]. All answers I saw had the range function. Now I am using Python 3. On executing the range function to create a list, I have seen that code executes slowly, popping 1 digit at a time because range is a generator function.

Is there an alternative to create a list of consecutive numbers(assuming a very large one) that doesn't use a generator function like range so that there is no slow down? I can use a C type approach of checking if n < N but is there a more Pythonic way of doing it?

Please run this code in IDLE to understand my question more clearly:

```
x = list(range(14))
for n in x:
    print(n)
```

Comment: _"Now I am using Python 3. On executing the range function to create a list, I have seen that code executes slowly, **popping 1 digit at a time range because range is a generator function**."_ - I'm not really sure what you're talking about here. Could you show some example code?

Comment: `list(range(size))` creates a list of numbers much faster than any explicit Python loop, because most of the work is being done at C speed. But are you sure you really need an actual list? Why can't you use a generator?

Comment: Code in your loop might be incompatible with Python 3, I don't think range is the issue.

Comment: @ChristianDean- "popping 1 digit at a time because range is a generator function."(edited)
I have also added some code to the question.

Comment: if nothing is "FAST" enough for you, maybe cPython is not for you. Try using PyPy. It is currently 7.5 times faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I checked and found that the delay I was talking about was not because of using the generator. It looks like IDLE executes the print statement slowly as compared to my IDE PyCharm. In Pycharm, all the output is printed together and instantly.

The same code runs much slower in IDLE compared to Pycharm.

Answer (score 3):

In general, using generators *is* the Pythonic way to do it. Generators tend to be *very* fast in Python. Let's start by just looking at different ways of creating a precomputed list of N integers:

```
import timeit

print(
    "Generating list from range:",
    timeit.timeit("list(range(100))")
)
print(
    "Generating list with comprehension:",
    timeit.timeit("[i for i in range(100)]")
)
print(
    "Generating list with while:",
    timeit.timeit(
        """\
i = 0
res = []
while i < 100:
    res.append(i)
    i += 1"""
    )
)
```

On my system (with Python 3.5.2), this gives:

```
Generating list from range: 1.0031339479999133
Generating list with comprehension: 3.2253709860001436
Generating list with while: 12.400529407000022
```

So, just directly converting the range object to a list gives the best performance if you're just trying to create a precomputed list of N integers. Now, let's see what happens when iterating on a precomputed list vs. iterating on a range object:

```
print(
    "Precomputed range:",
    timeit.timeit(
        '[x for x in seq]',
        setup='seq = range(100)'
    )
)

print(
    "Precomputed list:",
    timeit.timeit(
        '[x for x in seq]',
        setup='seq = list(range(100))'
    )
)
```

On my system, this yields

```
Precomputed range: 3.063208956000153
Precomputed list: 3.0270772009998836
```

The performance difference from iterating on a range object vs. a precomputed list is negligible. So, in general, I would give preference to just using a range object if you need an iterable with N integers, regardless of performance considerations.